# Google Calendar API Batch Request from localhost has been blocked

Tags: javascript

I am getting, "*from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*." error while testing Google Calendar API V3 by submitting the batch request from localhost. I was able to test batch submit a couple of months back but now I get this error?

This is the batch request I am sending to google api via Ajax POST

```
function batch(data,calendarId){
        var boundary = 'xxxxxxxx';
        var batchRequest = '';
        var payload = data.filter(function(curr,i,arr){
            batchRequest = batchRequest + 
                           "--"+boundary +
                           '\r\nContent-Type:application/http'+
                           '\r\nContent-ID:'+i+'\r\n\r\nPOST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'+calendarId+'/events'+
                           '\r\nContent-Type: application/json' +
                           '\r\n\r\n' + JSON.stringify(curr) + "\r\n";
        });
        payload = batchRequest +'\r\n'+'--'+boundary+'--';
        return payload;
    }
```

Any thoughts or inputs ?

Thanks
Ravi

Tried sending batch request to google calendar api 3 from localhost?
Expecting solution to test batch request from localhost to google calendar api 3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved.

I was using method:'POST' instead of type:'POST' in ajax parameters, which was sending the request as 'GET' instead of 'POST' hence google calendar api blocking the request.

Thank you and closing the issue.